# Reducer result not reflecting correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an **action dispatcher** that picks up comments from a blog post, straight from an `API` server first then dispatch an action.

```
export function fetchPostComments(postID) {
 return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`${url}/posts/${postID}/comments`, { method: 'GET', headers})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((comments) => {console.log("action ", comments); dispatch(getPostComments(comments))})
    .catch((error)=>{console.log('fetch comments error',error)});          
};}
```

I `console.log`it as you see above, and it gives the result I am looking for, as shown below.

[image]

And here is how I dispatch an **action**.

```
export function getPostComments (comments) {
 return {
  type: GET_POST_COMMENTS,
  comments
 }
}
```

And now here is my **reducer**:

```
function comments (state = {}, action) {
 switch (action.type) {
  case GET_POST_COMMENTS:
      console.log("Reducer comments ", action.comments);
      return action.comments;
  default :
      return state
 }
}
```

If you observe again, I use a `console.log` to confirm the result and again I have the correct result that I desired as shown below:

[image]

Now, in one of my component, I display the blog post information and a link to view comments. Once the user click the view comments, it triggers the calling of the action dispatcher.

```
 <div className="row">
     <a onClick={this.handleFetchComments} href=""><span className="float-date"><strong style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>View Comments</strong></span></a>
 </div>
 <div>
      <div>
           <span>Count :  { this.state.comments.length }</span>
      </div>
      <textarea placeholder="Add your comments here"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="+Add comment" />        
 </div>
```

This is the **handler** to fetch comments:

```
 handleFetchComments = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const comments = this.props.getAllComments(this.props.postID);
    console.log("Comments fetch ", comments);
    setInterval(this.loadComments(comments),1000);
 }

 loadComments(comm) {
    console.log("Before ", this.state.comments);
    this.setState(()=>({comments:comm}));
    console.log("After ", this.state.comments);
 }
```

I put some `console.log` just to check the result and this is the result which I get, which is wrong and not compatible with the result produced by the reducer a moment ago. It gives me an undefined and empty result from a dispatch action, as shown in the result below:

[image]

Meanwhile, my `Redux` **Dev tools** every time I clicked the View Comments link, it shows up the correct data that I desired and triggers the dispatch action as shown below.

[image]

This is my **state** by the way on my `Component`, that has the link to **View Comments**:

```
state = {
    post: [],
    hasClickComments : false,
    comments: []
}
```

This is my `mapStateToProps` in my `App.js`:

```
function mapStateToProps ({posts, comments, categories}) {  
 return {
  posts: posts,
  comments: comments,
  categories: categories,
 }
}
```

And this is my `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
 return {
  getAllComments: (postID) => dispatch(fetchPostComments(postID)),
 }
}
```

I have other actions that I dispatch also `mapDispatchtoProps` and it's all working so far, except for this one.

I am new to `React` and `Redux`, and I am looking for the solution for this one almost two days but could not figure it out. What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix React Component's State and props.[State And Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props)

after `mapStateToProps` all the data become the component's props.

and you should use `this.props.comments` to get your data!

Comment: I tried to pass comments as props from App.js to a grandchild component and use it to display the data but it is still not working. Thanks for this tip by the way.

Comment: would you please show your ```store```  code  and the ```combineReducer```

Comment: Reading the link you provided it gives me some insight. I thought for a while that only `state` could prompt re-render but it turned out that `props` do that as well. I was now able to pick up the comments as it should be. Thanks once again. GOD bless.

Answer (score 0):

```
function comments (state = {}, action) {
 switch (action.type) {
  case GET_POST_COMMENTS:
      console.log("Reducer comments ", action.comments);
      return {
         ...state,
         comments: action.comments;
        }

  default :
      return state
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this one, but still the same results. Thanks for the help.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If your comment data is in redux then might be the problem is the way you are using mapStateToProps.
I suggest you to use debugger in function and find what you are getting in state.

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {  
 debugger
//return {
 // posts: posts,
 // comments: comments,
 // categories: categories,
 //}
}
```

now look at the data in state on the console.
then assign the data to required variables.

Comment: I'll try this one.